# How to customize a CollectionType() item?

Tags: symfony, twig

This [§ of the Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field) shows an awesome technique for customizing an individual field. I'm using it a lot but there is one particular `Type` for which I'm having a hard time doing the customization : the `CollectionType()` Customizing the collection itself is quite easy, you can do something like this:

```
{% block _mynamespace_mybundle_mytype_mycollectionfield_row %}
{% if prototype is defined %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': form_widget(prototype) }) %}
{% endif %}
{% spaceless %}
    <ul {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% spaceless %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {% for child in form %}
            <li>
              {{form_widget(child)}}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endspaceless %}
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </ul>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

But how can you customize each element of the collection ? And how can you customize the `data-prototype` using Twig (the `data-prototype` is a special attribute used to add new items with js)?

I tried doing something like this (for the `data-prototype`):

```
{% block _mynamespace_mybundle_mytype_mycollectionfield_$$name$$_row %}
customization ok!
{% endblock %}
```

But I get errors, because I don't know how to escape the `$`

Regarding the items, I tried many things:

```
{% block _mynamespace_mybundle_mytype_mycollectionfield_item_subfield_row %}
customization ok!
{% endblock %}

{% block _mynamespace_mybundle_mytype_mycollectionfield_element_subfield_row %}
customization ok!
{% endblock %}
```

None of them work.

Comment: What do you mean with customizing the data-prototype using Twig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in symfony's bug tracker, and it seems there is no solution, but a good workaround is creating a custom type for each subfield you want to customize. See [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2663)